# Apache Wicket 9.1 CSRF

Tags: wicket

I'm trying to understand the Apache Wicket 9.1 documentation what comes to CSRF protection. https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_csrf_protection

I'm not totally sure if the CSRF protection is enabled by default for actions? Or, does that require that I will introduce a ResourceIsolationRequestCycleLister in my WicketApplication and only after that the actions are CSRF protected?

```
@Override
 protected void init() {
  super.init();
  getRequestCycleListeners().add(new ResourceIsolationRequestCycleListener());
  // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the later part is true, i.e. only after introducing ResourceIsolationRequestCycleLister in your application the actions are CSRF protected while page request are not checked.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. I can now see CSRF protection being in place, as my tests are getting broken. I am using WicketTester and giving the above mentioned WicketApplication (where the ResourceIsolationRequestCycleListener is being set) as constructor parameter. Should I somehow disable CSRF for tests, or do I need to configure the WicketTester or FormTesters somehow?

Comment: What you did in your tests should be enough. Maybe you can find some help looking at the test case of ResourceIsolationRequestCycleListener (see link below).
If you still have problem please create another question to better track your problem.

https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/f865d85e7c5f86cf37d09e274c25864633fdfa25/wicket-core/src/test/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/ResourceIsolationRequestCycleListenerTest.java